# Unable to mock XSSFWorkbook class in Junit

Tags: java, mockito, apache-poi, junit5

The Java code below runs fine and the functionalities work as expected. However, it fails during Junit. it says "*Unexpected exception thrown:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.newDocumentBuilder()Ljavax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder;*" although I mocked it.

Full stack trace

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLRelation.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRelation.<init>(XSSFRelation.java:375)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRelation.<clinit>(XSSFRelation.java:47)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookType.<clinit>(XSSFWorkbookType.java:26)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:48)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.instance.ObjenesisInstantiator.newInstance(ObjenesisInstantiator.java:19)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:182)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1907)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1816)
    at com.commerce.CommandDetailsTest.setUp(GetMetaDataHowtoVideoBeforeUpdateTest.java:37)
```

Java code

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); //JUNIT error - Unexpected exception thrown: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.newDocumentBuilder()Ljavax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder;
```

Junit Code

```
Workbook workbook;

@BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws NoSuchFieldException, FileNotFoundException {
        workbook = mock(XSSFWorkbook.class);
    }
@Test
    void executeTest() throws LoginException, RepositoryException {
        Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(() ->getData.getCommand(workItem, wfSession, data));
    }
workbook = mock(XSSFWorkbook.class);
```

Added below dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And both main java class and junit test classes uses same dependencies

Comment: Hello. You are facing `NoSuchMethodError`. It seems like the issue is not with your mocking but rather with a possible version conflict between your dependencies. If you're using Apache POI 4, make sure you have the correct dependency for `poi-ooxml`. You should have two dependencies, e.g.: `poi:4.1.2` and `poi-ooxml:4.1.2`. Make sure your JUnit tests are using the same dependencies as your main code.

Comment: I have the correct dependencies. Let me the update the same in original question for your info. Both main java class and junit uses the same dependencies. Any other idea ?

Comment: Remove the `provided` scope from the `Apache POI` and `XMLBeans` dependencies in your `pom.xml` file. The `provided` scope means that the dependencies will be available at compile time, but not at runtime.

Comment: "The provided dependencies are available only at compile time and in the test classpath of the project. These dependencies are also not transitive" - from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes). Perhaps I made a small mistake in the previous comment, but let's try anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I removed provided scope in all three above dependencies. Now I get Unexpected exception thrown: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookType. Any idea?

Comment: The `NoClassDefFoundError` can occur when the JVM is unable to find the class definition at runtime, even though the class was present at compile time. Try to clean and rebuild the project (top IDEA bar -> Build -> Rebuild Project), reload maven dependencies, and also run the maven clean build.

Comment: I'd like to ask one more question. Does this behavior unique to the tests or do you occur the same in the application?

Comment: Many time I tried to rebuild and clean the project in eclipse and restarted my machine :). I am also updating maven dependencies using "mvn clean install -U" command. I don t see this issue in application, application is working as expected. it fails only at junit level.

Comment: I added a full stack trace. Could you please check it you could find any lead

Comment: We may try to make a bad thing. Do you use features of newer versions? Can we downgrade to ver. 4? If you ready to do this - let's downgrade versions of POI, POI OOXML to 4.1.2, also add dependency poi-ooxml-schemas (also 4.1.2) and add [commons-collections4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.4)

Comment: Mykola - I have no issue in downgrading POI version. infact i had 3.17 version. I changed the version to 4.1.2 for both POI, POI OOXML and added commons-collections4 with 4.4 version but still I get following error - Unexpected exception thrown: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookType
[ERROR]  Unexpected exception thrown: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.newDocumentBuilder()Ljavax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder;